# podman inside podman: works only with "privileged" while it works without for the official podman image

Tags: linux, dockerfile, containers, podman

I am trying to create a podman image that allows me to run rootless podman inside rootless podman.
I have read https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-inside-container
and tried to build an image analogous to `quay.io/podman/stable:latest` based on top of `docker.io/python:3.10-slim-bullseye` or `docker.io/ubuntu:22.04`,
but somehow my images require `--privileged` which the quay.io/podman fedora-based image does not.

For reference, here **what does work for `quay.io/podman/stable:latest`**:

```
$ podman run --rm \
    --security-opt label=disable \
    --device /dev/fuse \
    --user podman \
    quay.io/podman/stable:latest podman info
```

prints the podman info and no warning/errors, also `podman run hellow-world` works inside the container as expected.

I have created a dockerfile for a debian/ubuntu-based image that allows running rootless podman inside. The dockerfile closely follows https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-inside-container and https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/contrib/podmanimage/stable/Containerfile
and is shown at the bottom.

However, the resulting image (call it podinpodtest) **does not work as expected**:

```
$ podman run --rm \
    --security-opt label=disable \
    --device /dev/fuse \
    --user podman \
    podinpodtest podman info
```

results in **`Error: cannot setup namespace using newuidmap: exit status 1`**.

Adding `--privileged` makes the image work:

```
$ podman run --rm \
    --security-opt label=disable \
    --device /dev/fuse \
    --user podman \
    --privileged \
    podinpodtest podman info
```

correctly prints the podman info.

1. Why does the debian/ubuntu based image require `--privileged` for running rootless podman inside of it?
2. I do not want to run the image with `--privileged` – can the debian/ubuntu based image be fixed to work similarly to the quay.io/podman image?

---

```
#FROM docker.io/python:3.10-slim-bullseye
FROM docker.io/ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    containers-storage \
    fuse-overlayfs \
    libvshadow-utils \
    podman \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd podman; \
echo "podman:1:999\npodman:1001:64535" > /etc/subuid; \
echo "podman:1:999\npodman:1001:64535" > /etc/subgid;

ARG _REPO_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containers/podman/main/contrib/podmanimage/stable"
ADD $_REPO_URL/containers.conf /etc/containers/containers.conf
ADD $_REPO_URL/podman-containers.conf /home/podman/.config/containers/containers.conf

RUN mkdir -p /home/podman/.local/share/containers && \
    chown podman:podman -R /home/podman && \
    chmod 644 /etc/containers/containers.conf

# Copy & modify the defaults to provide reference if runtime changes needed.
# Changes here are required for running with fuse-overlay storage inside container.
RUN sed -e 's|^#mount_program|mount_program|g' \
           -e '/additionalimage.*/a "/var/lib/shared",' \
           -e 's|^mountopt[[:space:]]*=.*$|mountopt = "nodev,fsync=0"|g' \
           /usr/share/containers/storage.conf \
           > /etc/containers/storage.conf

# Note VOLUME options must always happen after the chown call above
# RUN commands can not modify existing volumes
VOLUME /var/lib/containers
VOLUME /home/podman/.local/share/containers

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/shared/overlay-images \
             /var/lib/shared/overlay-layers \
             /var/lib/shared/vfs-images \
             /var/lib/shared/vfs-layers && \
    touch /var/lib/shared/overlay-images/images.lock && \
    touch /var/lib/shared/overlay-layers/layers.lock && \
    touch /var/lib/shared/vfs-images/images.lock && \
    touch /var/lib/shared/vfs-layers/layers.lock

ENV _CONTAINERS_USERNS_CONFIGURED=""
```

Comment: Did you ever work this out? Been bashing my head against it too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. While installing docker I ran the following commands

```
grep "$USER" /etc/subuid >> /dev/null 2&>1 || (echo "$USER:100000:65536" | sudo tee -a /etc/subuid)
grep "$USER" /etc/subgid >> /dev/null 2&>1 || (echo "$USER:100000:65536" | sudo tee -a /etc/subgid)
```

This is taken from the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#:%7E:text=Docker%20Desktop%20maps%20the%20current,above%200%20in%20the%20containers.) this for some reason added duplicate entries for my user in the files /etc/subgid and /etc/subuid. Once I got rid of the duplicate values both docker and podman were able to run in rootles mode